# ¿Cómo puedo correr un proyecto de intellij idea desde cmd?

Tags: java, cmd

Tengo un programa en C# que crea programas en Java a base de plantillas, pero sólo lo hacía en consola y ahora quiero que funcione para Java en visual. Tengo mi pequeño proyecto en una carpeta y ya usé el código:

```
javac -d Carpeta_clases -cp ArchivosJavaArchivosJava/com/package/Programa.java
```

y todo bien hasta ahí, pero a la hora de teclear el comando:

```
java -cp ArchivosJava com.package.Programa
```

me sale este error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at com.codebin.App.(App.java:14)
>           at com.codebin.App.main(App.java:31)

El código es el siguiente:

```
package com.codebin;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class App {
    private JButton button_msg;
    private JPanel panelMain;

    public App() {
        button_msg.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hola mundo");
            }
        });
        button_msg.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Has salido");
                super.mouseExited(e);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Aplicación");
        frame.setContentPane(new App().panelMain);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Debo aclarar que lo que dije de la línea de comandos era un ejemplo. Por si me dicen que el ejemplo está mal escrito, en la consola sí lo escribo como debe ser.

Si alguno conoce algún .bat que compile con argumentos estos proyectos sería bienvenido.

Comment: Evita poner detalles innecesarios en las preguntas, porque confunden a la gente, y además te hacen más difícil a tí mismo buscar si la pregunta ya está contestada en otra parte. Esto no tiene nada que ver ni con C#, ni con IntelliJ, ni con línea de comandos. Es simplemente un `NullPointerException` al ejecutar un programa Java.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)